# Sum dictionary values stored in Data frame Columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame having dictionary like structure. I want to only sum the values and store into new column.

```
Column 1         Desired Output
[{'Apple':3},          9
 {'Mango:2},
 {'Peach:4}]

[{'Blue':2},           3
 {'Black':1}]             


df['Desired Output'] = [sum(x) for x in df['Column 1']]
df
```

Comment: `sum(x)` won't work because `x` is a dictionary, and `df["Column 1"]` is a list of separate dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Column 1` column does indeed have dictionaries (and not strings that look like dictionaries), this should do the trick:

```py
df['Desired Output'] = df["Column 1"].apply(lambda lst: sum(sum(d.values()) for d in lst))
```

Comment: Go ahead and accept the answer in that case! Glad I could help!